# How to remove the last line of text with python?

Tags: python

I use this code to write txt:

```
myList =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
with open(r'D:/abc.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as fo:
    for row in myList:
        list1 = [(str(item) + " ") for item in row]
        fo.writelines(list1)
        fo.write('\n')
```

In fact, the result is 4 lines,and the last line is empty.

The '\n' makes the last empty line.

How to remove the last line?

Comment: Write it all at once rather than line by line: `'\n'.join(appropriate comprehension)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join` instead would be better:

```
with open(r'D:/abc.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as fo:
    fo.write('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str,i)) for i in myList]))
```

When you open `abc.txt`, it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Yes,very helpful!

Comment: @Rhaegal Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: @Rhaegal Remember to [`accept and upvote`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)